# Java Spring JPA изменить поле в БД

Tags: java, jpa

Есть табличка с id и owner.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String owner;
    ....
// Getters, Setters and Constructors
```

Кладу в БД так:

```
    @PostMapping("/main")
public String add (
        @RequestParam String owner,
        @RequestParam String text,
        @RequestParam String sn, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Message message = new Message (text, sn, owner);
                messageRepo2.save(message);
}
    return "main";
```

Работа с данными

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface MessageRepo2 extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
```

Подскажите как изменить owner в таблице postgres? Любой вариант подойдёт (удалить>добавить новое или изменить).
Пробовал что-то типа

```
@Modifying
@Query("update message set owner = ?1 where id = ?2")
int setFixedOwnerFor(String owner, Integer id);
```

но приложение не запускается с ошибкой:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageModify': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int com.example.webapp.repos.MessageModify.setFixedOwnerFor(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)!

Comment: Попробуйте @Query("update Message m set m.owner = ?1 where m.id = ?2")

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Параметров для SET на самом деле больше и, видимо, имеет значение в каком порядке их расставлять в объекте и, само собой, в запросе.

Comment: В запросе да, порядок имеет значение. В объекте - нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обработка запроса:

```
    @PostMapping("/update")
public String modifyowner (
        @RequestParam String owner,
        @RequestParam String sn,
        @RequestParam String text,
        @RequestParam Integer id,
        Map<String, Object> model) {
    Message messages = new Message (owner, id, sn, text);
    messageModify.save(messages);
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "/main";
}
```

Запрос:

```
@Transactional
 public interface MessageModify extends CrudRepository<Message, Long>{
@Modifying
@Query("update Message m set m.owner = ?1,  m.text = ?2, m.sn = ?3 where m.id = ?4")
 String setFixedOwnerFor(String owner, String text, String sn, Integer id);
```

}

Конструктор

```
    public Message(String owner, Integer id, String sn, String text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.sn = sn;
    this.text = text;
}
```